# SL3/SL4 - Ado.Net Data Services Error during new DataServiceCollection<T>(queryResponse)

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, wcf-data-services

Hey all, I have two functions in a SL project (VS2010) that do almost exactly the same thing, yet one throws an error and the other does not. It seems to be related to the projections, but I am unsure about the best way to resolve.

The function that works is...

```
public void LoadAllChunksExpandAll(DataHelperReturnHandler handler, string orderby)
    {
        DataServiceCollection<CmsChunk> data = null;

        DataServiceQuery<CmsChunk> theQuery = _dataservice
            .CmsChunks
            .Expand("CmsItemState")
            .AddQueryOption("$orderby", orderby);

        theQuery.BeginExecute(
            delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            {
                _callback_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DataServiceQuery<CmsChunk> query = asyncResult.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<CmsChunk>;
                                if (query != null)
                                {
                                    //create a tracked DataServiceCollection from the result of the asynchronous query.
                                    QueryOperationResponse<CmsChunk> queryResponse =
                                        query.EndExecute(asyncResult) as QueryOperationResponse<CmsChunk>;
                                    data = new DataServiceCollection<CmsChunk>(queryResponse);

                                    handler(data);
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                handler(data);
                            }
                        }
                    );
            },
            theQuery
        );
    }
```

This compiles and runs as expected. A very, very similar function (shown below) fails...

```
             public void LoadAllPagesExpandAll(DataHelperReturnHandler handler, string orderby)
    {
        DataServiceCollection<CmsPage> data = null;

        DataServiceQuery<CmsPage> theQuery = _dataservice
            .CmsPages
            .Expand("CmsChildPages")
            .Expand("CmsParentPage")
            .Expand("CmsItemState")
            .AddQueryOption("$orderby", orderby);

        theQuery.BeginExecute(
            delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            {
                _callback_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DataServiceQuery<CmsPage> query = asyncResult.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<CmsPage>;
                                if (query != null)
                                {
                                    //create a tracked DataServiceCollection from the result of the asynchronous query.
                                    QueryOperationResponse<CmsPage> queryResponse = query.EndExecute(asyncResult) as QueryOperationResponse<CmsPage>;
                                    data = new DataServiceCollection<CmsPage>(queryResponse);

                                    handler(data);
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                handler(data);
                            }
                        }
                    );
            },
            theQuery
        );
    }
```

Clearly the issue is the Expand projections that involve a self referencing relationship (pages can contain other pages).  This is under SL4 or SL3 using ADONETDataServices SL3 Update CTP3.

I am open to any work around or pointers to goo information, a Google search for the error results in two hits, neither particularly helpful that I can decipher.

The short error is "An item could not be added to the collection. When items in a DataServiceCollection are tracked by the DataServiceContext, new items cannot be added before items have been loaded into the collection."

The full error is...

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   was caught   Message=Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeType typeOwner)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object
>   obj, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.ClientType.ClientProperty.SetValue(Object
>   instance, Object value, String
>   propertyName, Boolean allowAdd)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.ApplyItemsToCollection(AtomEntry
>   entry, ClientProperty property,
>   IEnumerable items, Uri nextLink,
>   ProjectionPlan continuationPlan)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.ApplyFeedToCollection(AtomEntry
>   entry, ClientProperty property,
>   AtomFeed feed, Boolean includeLinks)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.MaterializeResolvedEntry(AtomEntry
>   entry, Boolean includeLinks)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Materialize(AtomEntry
>   entry, Type expectedEntryType, Boolean
>   includeLinks)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.DirectMaterializePlan(AtomMaterializer
>   materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type
>   expectedEntryType)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializerInvoker.DirectMaterializePlan(Object
>   materializer, Object entry, Type
>   expectedEntryType)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.ProjectionPlan.Run(AtomMaterializer
>   materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type
>   expectedType)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Read()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__b1`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.InternalLoadCollection(IEnumerable`1 items)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.StartTracking(DataServiceContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 items, String
>   entitySet, Func`2 entityChanged,
>   Func`2 collectionChanged)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1..ctor(DataServiceContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 items,
>   TrackingMode trackingMode, String
>   entitySetName, Func`2
>   entityChangedCallback, Func`2
>   collectionChangedCallback)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   items)
>          at Phinli.Dashboard.Silverlight.Helpers.DataHelper.<>c__DisplayClass44.<>c__DisplayClass46.<LoadAllPagesExpandAll>b__43()
>   InnerException:
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>          Message=An item could not be added to the collection. When items in
>   a DataServiceCollection are tracked by
>   the DataServiceContext, new items
>   cannot be added before items have been
>   loaded into the collection.
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, T item)
>               at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T
>   item)
>          InnerException:

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little like a bug in Data Services.

I'll follow up with the Data Services Team and get back to you with an answer.

Might take a couple of days because of the weekend.

[Alex James](http://twitter.com/adjames)

Data Services PM

Comment: I appreciate you guys looking into it, please let me know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the DataServiceCollection is failing to add the downloaded entities into the corresponding DataServiceCollection properties of the top level CMSPage types.We do some special casing to make sure that the DataServiceCollection can only be used after its started tracking some objects.  I'll investigate this later, meanwhile try this code instead :

```
public void LoadAllPagesExpandAll(DataHelperReturnHandler handler, string orderby) 
{ 
  DataServiceCollection<CmsPage> data = new   DataServiceCollection<CmsPage>( _dataservice );

  DataServiceQuery<CmsPage> theQuery = _dataservice 
      .CmsPages 
      .Expand("CmsChildPages") 
      .Expand("CmsParentPage") 
      .Expand("CmsItemState") 
      .AddQueryOption("$orderby", orderby); 

  theQuery.BeginExecute( 
      delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
      { 
    _callback_dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
      () => 
      { 
          try 
          { 
        DataServiceQuery<CmsPage> query = asyncResult.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<CmsPage>; 
        if (query != null) 
        { 
            //create a tracked DataServiceCollection from the result of the asynchronous query. 
            QueryOperationResponse<CmsPage> queryResponse = query.EndExecute(asyncResult) as QueryOperationResponse<CmsPage>; 
            data.Load(queryResponse); 

            handler(data); 
        } 
          } 
          catch 
          { 
        handler(data); 
          } 
      } 
        ); 
      }, 
      theQuery 
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it... sadly no, still the same exception at the same point.